# IIS Digest Authentication against multiple domains

Tags: iis, authentication

How do I authenticate across multiple (AD) domains on IIS 6 using digest authentication?  Is the domain that the server resides on the only authenticate-able domain?

Answer (score 1):

While MS documentation isnt particularly clear in this point, making some search we see on [Autentification Methods on IIS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324274/en-us):

- It connects to a DC for validating the user and pass on both methods, but digest uses MD5 to send user and pass (¡Problem of security!)

So, if you look for integrated method, there's posts where explains that multidomain access is correct if you have a trust relationship between those domains. [MultiDomain IIS](http://forums.iis.net/t/1134630.aspx)

**I think we can suppose that Multidomain works with digest method with trust relations between domains, based on MS info**

Question: Can't you switch to integrated to use Kerberos and improve security? MD5 is quite easy to crack.

Hope this helps.